# How do I join an array by addition operation in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two array definition and I want to do addition operation element by element without looping operation? for example:

```
decimal[] xx = { 1, 2, 3 };
decimal[] yy = { 6, 7, 8 };
```

the result I want is:

```
decimal[] zz = { 7, 9, 11 };
```

the addition operation is simple. Just add one by one for each element like

```
decimal[] zz = decimal[xx.Length];
for (int i=0; i<xx.Length;i++){
   zz[i] =xx[i] + yy[i];
}
```

But I don't want to use looping operation.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the loop?

Comment: Why do you perform addition 3 times per loop???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that without looping some way or the other.

Your array creation and loop should be:

```
decimal[] zz = new decimal[xx.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < xx.Length; i++){
   zz[i] = xx[i] + yy[i];
}
```

Or a more compact, but somewhat less readable version:

```
decimal[] zz = new decimal[xx.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < xx.Length; zz[i++] = xx[i] + yy[i]);
```

You can also use Linq extensions to do the looping:

```
decimal[] zz = xx.Select((x, i) => x + yy[i]).ToArray();
```

Or:

```
decimal[] zz = Enumerable.Range(0, xx.Length).Select(i => xx[i]+yy[i]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
decimal[] zz = xx.Zip(yy, (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();
```

Comment: ...but it's trivial to write a replacement for .Zip in .net 3.5: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqZip35.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
  var zz = xx.Select((x, i) => x + yy[i]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Will result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if `xx` is greater than  `yy`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter And `Zip` will sliently ignore it. Is it better?

Comment: Depends. I just wanted to comment it. It might be an option to use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) instead of the indexer here. Then this approach would even have an additional advantage over `Enumerable.Zip`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
var zz = Enumerable
             .Range(0, (int)Math.Min(xx.Length, yy.Length))
             .Select(i => xx[i] + yy[i])
             .ToArray();
```

but that's really just moving the looping behind-the-scenes.

Comment: This is the best way for .NET 3.5, since `Enumerable.Zip` requires .NET 4.0.

Comment: Will result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if `xx` is greater than `yy`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) beside `Zip`:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, xx.Length)
                       .Select(i => xx[i] + yy[i])
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: [Second argument is a count, not a maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).

Comment: This code will return an array with one less element than `xx` has.

Comment: Will result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if `xx` is greater than `yy`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: got it, seems `Zip` would be the best

Answer (score 0):

If they are globally scoped arrays you could use recursion

```
public void add(int index){

  zz[index] = xx[index] + yy[index];

  if(index < xx.Length){
     add(index+1);

   }

}
```

Is psuedo-code, untested, but represents general idea. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: As this is the only answer thus far that doesn't use a loop, I don't think it's worth a -1 :p

Comment: Thank you! I make no guarantee as to its optimality, but hope it satisfies the brief!